# Can I have a catch all not matched requests using Spring DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using the  Spring MVC for a project, and I am using the Spring DispatcherServlet to map the request's coming into the application to the controllers written elsewhere. I am looking for a way to have a default handler ( a catch all handler) if the request doesn't map to any of the exisiting controller-view maps. This currently shows a Resource not found exception, but I want to know if a catch all unmatched requests function is available in the Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `HandlerMapping` strategy in Spring MVC has [a `defaultHandler` property](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMapping.html#setDefaultHandler%28java.lang.Object%29) for just this purpose.

This is easy if your Spring config is already specifying a `HandlerMapping` object explicitly (e.g. a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`), but it's less obvious if you're relying on the defaults to supply a `HandlerMapping` for you.

For example, if you're using annotated controllers, then you're probably relaying on the default declaration of `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` which Spring supplies automatically. However, you can provide your own bean to override the default:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
   <property name="defaultHandler" ref="myDefaultHandler"/>
</bean>
```

This same pattern will work with any `Handlermapping` type, just substitute the class name.

Comment: Does the class you reference need to be an implementation of Controller?  Or can it be annotated as a Controller?  I did the latter, and added a handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) method and it doesn't seem to invoke this.  I keep getting the 400 response that it was syntactically incorrect.